# Excel: copy value of a cell to another depending on values of others

Tags: excel, list, vlookup

I've been trying to make a list of people working at a firm and their hometowns. The problem now is that I'd like to automatically fill in the "province" column, depending on the postal code.

For example: it can be seen in the image that the postal code range of "Luik" is between B-4000 and B-4999, so if the postal code of a town is 4043, the province column should have the value "Luik".

I thought of making another column in which the postal code would be reduced to a round number, say 4043 would become 4000 using `IF` functions, and comparing that to the first value of the range using the `VLOOKUP` function, but that would not really be a pain in the butt. Can anyone help me in doing this an easier way?

[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF5Fw.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the province name and display it in the same column. Here's a formula that will do that:

```
=IF(AND(INT(RIGHT(A1,4))>3999, INT(RIGHT(A1,4))<5000),"Luik","another province")
```

Here's that same formula broken up for readability:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        INT(RIGHT(A1,4))>3999,
        INT(RIGHT(A1,4))<5000
    ),
    "Liuk",
    "another province"
)
```

`A1` would be replaced with the cell that you want to check. (Obviously, once you put this formula into one cell, you can drag it down to autofill others in the same column.)

If you have multiple provinces to choose from, you can use nested `IF` statements to get the correct province based on postal code.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(B2,E:E))
```

The column in which the start numbers are found, in your picture, the 5th column, needs to be sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, CHOOSE({1,2,3},$E:$E,$F:$F,$D:$D),3,TRUE)
```

1. B1 is the value we're going to be looking up in the table.
2. CHOOSE is to inverse column D with E and F which is the format VLOOKUP is waiting for.
3. TRUE is to say to VLOOKUP to around the value from B1.

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey Olaru Victor, thanks for the reaction! I've tried doing this a couple of ways, but i never get a result, there's two different options, which generate different problems: 

=VERT.ZOEKEN([@[Post code/ZIP]];KIEZEN({1;2;3};$H:$H;$I:$I;$J:$J);8;WAAR()) results in an "invalid cell reference" note 

=VERT.ZOEKEN([@[Post code/ZIP]];KIEZEN({1;2;3};H$2:H$12;I$2:I$12;J$2:J$12);8;WAAR()) results in "value not available" 

VERT.ZOEKEN = VLOOKUP, KIEZEN = CHOOSE, WAAR = TRUE 

https://imgur.com/a/LGuwl

Comment: You have to write KIEZEN({1,2,3},$I:$I,$J:$J,$H:$H) instead of KIEZEN({1;2;3};$H:$H;$I:$I;$J:$J). I put column H at the end. The function KIEZEN which I suppose is CHOOSE is to put the column H after column I and J because VLOOKUP is working with columns from left to right.